# extract text between certain characters in R

Tags: r, regex

I need to capture `TEST_WF1_CORP[-application-com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer]` from the following string, basically from `-` to `@` sign.

```
i<-c("Current CPU load - TEST_WF1_CORP[-application-com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer]@example1.com")
```

I've tried this:

```
str_match(i, ".*-([^\\.]*)\\@.*")[,2]
```

I am getting NA, any ideas?

Comment: try `.*?-(.*?)@.*`

Answer (score 5):

**1) gsub** Replace everything up to and including `-`, i.e. `.* -`, and everything after and including `@`, i.e. `@.*`, with a zero length string.  No packages are needed:

```
gsub(".* - |@.*", "", i)
## "TEST_WF1_CORP[-application-com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer]"
```

**2) sub** This would also work.  It matches everything to space, minus, space (i.e. `.* -`) and then captures everything until `@` (i.e. `(.*)@` ) followed by whatever is left (`.*`) and replaces that with the capture group, i.e. the part within parens.  It also uses no packages.

```
sub(".*- (.*)@.*", "\\1", i)
## [1] "TEST_WF1_CORP[-application-com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer]"
```

**Note:** We used this as input `i`:

```
i <- "Current CPU load - TEST_WF1_CORP[-application-com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer]@example1.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
-\s*([^@]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mUYpWs/1)

**Details**:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^@]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more chars other than `@`.

R demo:

```
> library(stringr)
> i<-c("Current CPU load - TEST_WF1_CORP[-application-com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer]@example1.com")
> str_match(i, "-\\s*([^@]+)")[,2]
[1] "TEST_WF1_CORP[-application-com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer]"
```

The same pattern can be used with base R `regmatches`/`regexec`:

```
> regmatches(i, regexec("-\\s*([^@]+)", i))[[1]][2]
[1] "TEST_WF1_CORP[-application-com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer]"
```

If you prefer a replacing approach you may use a `sub`:

```
> sub(".*?-\\s*([^@]+).*", "\\1", i)
[1] "TEST_WF1_CORP[-application-com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer]"
```

Here, `.*?` matches any 0+ chars,  as few as possible, up to the first `-`, then `-`, 0+ whitespaces (`\\s*`), then 1+ chars other than `@` are captured into Group 1 (see `([^@]+)`) and then `.*` matches the rest of the string. The `\1` in the replacement pattern puts the contents of Group 1 back into the replacement result.

Comment: Note that the stringr solution is great at handling NA values, `regmatches` has problems with it (you will need some more code), and `sub` will just return the original string if there is no match.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
extract <- unlist(strsplit(i,"- |@"))[2]
```